# HTML Title Attribute

Tags: html, css, image, title

On my website, I included images. I am currently displaying the copyright information for the images as a title attribute on the image tag.

I have recently found out that mobile browsers cannot display tooltips, meaning that the copyright information does not display on mobile. This is an issue.

I was wondering if there was a way to create a black bar at the bottom of the photo with the image's title attribute displayed on in?

---

**UPDATE:** Nevermind. I have decided that I will implement the `figcaption` element for all future images. Thanks for all of the answers though.

Comment: Yes, but you'll need JavaScript, given your current (implied) HTML, or you need to update your view somehow. Please post a "[mcve]" sample of your code, and an image showing the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<figure>` element to mark up a photo in a document in HTML 5.

```
<figure> 
    <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
    <figcaption>Fig.1 - A view of the pulpit rock in Norway.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Here is a link on [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figcaption.asp) to show you how it works!

*Hope this help!*

Comment: My website currently has over 1000 images with the copyright information in the title attribute, so I was hoping to extract it from there, as it would be impossible to add figcaption to all of my existing images.

Comment: '@ComputerWhiz'  (note the quotes) with regular expressions and macro keyboard recordings it is not that hard to automate changing loads of code.